# Which of these stories are in the same continuity as Batman: The Long Halloween?

Tags: dc, batman, canon, continuity

I've heard some conflicting reports as to exactly which DC comics and graphic novels are in the same continuity as *Batman: The Long Halloween*.

I know that *Batman: Dark Victory* and *Catwoman: When in Rome* are direct sequels, so they're definitely in the same series.

However, I've also heard people claim that *The Long Halloween* is in the same continuity as *Batman: Year One*, *The Dark Knight Returns*, the *Batman Annual* series, and *Robin: Year One*.

Then there is *Batman: Haunted Knight*, which has the same creative team and what appear to be identical character designs.

Which of these are truly in the same continuity as *The Long Halloween*? Are there any others that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

*Batman: Year One* (written/drawn by Frank Miller) along with *Batman: The Long Halloween, Batman: Dark Victory,* and *Catwoman: When in Rome* (all three written by Jeph Loeb/drawn by Tim Sale) share direct continuity with each other; *Robin: Year One* (written by Chuck Dixon and Scott Beatty/drawn by Javier Pulido and Marcos Martin) is generally held to be in the same continuity (as are the Batman Annual series - collected as the trade paperback *Batman: Four of a Kind*, written by Bob Kane, Chuck Dixon, Alan Grant, Doug Moench and all drawn by Brian Apthorp and featuring 'Year One' stories of Poison Ivy, Scarecrow, Riddler, and Man-Bat) although there are some inconsistencies, for example Jim Gordon's rank.

*Batman: Haunted Knight* is tricky. It collects three tales, all written by Jeph Loeb and drawn by Tim Sale - which subsequently led to the aforementioned collaborations *The Long Halloween, Dark Victory,* and *When in Rome*. Arguments still go on as to whether the timeline and events of any of the tales contained in *Haunted Knight* can be reconciled into consistency with those of *The Long Halloween, Dark Victory,* and *When in Rome* (which are generally placed in the 3rd and 4th years of Batman's career).

As for *The Dark Knight Returns* confusion sometimes arises here because *Batman: Year One* is actually held to be the 'start point' of two different DC continuities, a 'fork' if you like, leading to the main DC continuity as discussed above (lasting up until Flashpoint/The New 52) and also to the entirely separate so-called 'Miller-verse' (all Batman works, written - and sometimes drawn by - Frank Miller) comprising *Batman: Year One, All-Star Batman & Robin the Boy Wonder, Spawn/Batman, Dark Knight Returns: The Last Crusade, The Dark Knight Returns, The Dark Knight Strikes Again,* and *The Dark Knight III: The Master Race.*

Comment: this is all good info but a source / backing evidence would be helpful

Comment: I don't understand. These are things I know to be true. I've been a fan for over forty years, I own all bar two the titles concerned; I didn't have to look any of it up - other than to check my volumes for some of the creator names.

Comment: Should add that the two titles that I don't own I have read.

Comment: Who are you? In other words - unless you are one of the authors, illustrators, or otherwise involved in production, it's just your opinion unless you can back it up with objective facts (I would even say that citing consistencies within the materials and showing how other properties do not share those consistencies would at least be a start). I don't mean to disparage your years of fandom or knowledge, but, without citation, the answer requires future readers to take your word for it, which isn't a 'good' answer according to this site :)

Comment: I get what you're saying, but surely this site also seeks to benefit from personal knowledge? I _know_ that those that I said are in continuity _are_ in continuity. I know that those that I said are disputed _are_ disputed. Those things aren't my opinion. If I didn't _know_ I wouldn't have said so. Do I have to find a secondary source that also says what I know to be true just so that I can say "Such and such also says what I've just said"? If personal knowledge (not opinion) isn't acceptable then the people asking the original questions might just as well 'Google' instead of asking here.

Comment: Well, what if posted an answer that contradicted everything you said, and I likewise had no supporting material to substantiate those claims other than "I've read this stuff for 40 years, own everything, and I just *know*"? You see the trouble?. As to Google, I believe the intention of the site is that this is where you will eventually land if you *do* Google such a thing, and you'd find objective, fact-based, substantiated answers. Many times, questions are asked, not because the answer isn't known by the questioner, but precisely to create a record of resource for future Google-ers

Comment: here are some helpful Meta posts:
https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/answers-involving-ones-own-interpretation-of-the-work

https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/logical-speculation-in-answers  (key takeaway in this one is *evidence*) - in other words, you say you 'know are in continuity' - how? *Demonstrate how they are in continuity rather than just saying it is so*. Are there characters, events that only happen in those materials that is unique to them and nothing else, etc...? That's all I'm saying.